# Replacing elements in an array column in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have sample data as follows;

| team_id | mode |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [1,2] |

Here mode is an array.The goal is to replace the values in column `mode` by literal values, such as 1 stands for Ocean, and 2 stands for Air

**Expected Output**

| team_id | mode |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [Ocean,Air] |

**Present Approach**

As an attempt, I tried to first flatten the data into multiple rows;

| team_id | mode |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 2 |

Then we can define a new column assigning literal values to `mode` column using a `case` statement, followed by aggregating the values into an array to get desired output.

Can I get some help here to do the replacement directly in the array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many distinct modes could you have? Does it differ by team_id?

Answer (score 0):

Using `FLATTEN` and `ARRAY_AGG`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(team_id INT, mode ARRAY) AS SELECT 123, [1,2];

SELECT TEAM_ID,
    ARRAY_AGG(CASE f.value::TEXT
              WHEN 1 THEN 'Ocean'
              WHEN 2 THEN 'Air'
              ELSE 'Unknown'
              END) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY f.index) AS new_mode
FROM tab
,LATERAL FLATTEN(tab.mode) AS f
GROUP BY TEAM_ID;
```

Output:

| TEAM_ID | NEW_MODE |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [ "Ocean", "Air" ] |

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative solution with easy array manipulation. you could create a JS UDF:

```sql
create or replace function replace_vals_in_array(A variant)
returns variant
language javascript
as $$
dict = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'};
return A.map(x => dict[x]);
$$;
```

Then to update your table:

```sql
update arrs
set arr = replace_vals_in_array(arr);
```

Example setup:

```sql
create or replace temp table arrs as (
    select 1 id, [1,2,3] arr
    union all select 2, [2,4]
);

select *, replace_vals_in_array(arr)
from arrs;
```